# Unkind flag declined despite comment being unkind

Tags: discussion, unfriendly-or-unkind

I had a situation in which I [asked a user to clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934853/regex-in-htaccess-exclude-double-minus-sign) the requirements by adding the rules in the question and they did apparently:

[image]

Since it was just a copy / pasting I emphasized that *by rule I mean conditions where a rewrite rule should match* and they replied with something like *if it is not clear yet then perhaps you didn't sleep well yesterday*. However, both comments of me and OP got deleted after flags have been moderated (and yes *perhaps you didn't sleep well yesterday* is the exact phrase)

I flagged it as unkind / unfriendly but later I saw it was declined. But I wonder if it wasn't a proper reason for such a flag.

Comment: Unless the comment has already been deleted, they said no such thing.  They said that they think their question is clear, which, while you may not agree, is in no way "unkind".  They didn't say anything even close to what you quoted (again, unless it has since been deleted).  If the comment in question is any of the currently undeleted comments, please actually quote, precisely, the comment you feel is inappropriate.

Comment: I've had mixed results with such flags. no longer needed is almost always accepted in those situations, and unkind sometimes is accepted, other times not. If you're worried about how many declined flags you get, prioritize no longer needed... i'm not, so i flag based on whether or not i find it to be unkind or just not needed. This one in particular i would have also reached for unkind, if it's being characterized correctly above.

Comment: Both comments of me and OP got deleted after flags have been moderated.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I could flag it as no longer needed but actually I found the unkind reason more suitable.

Comment: I think your comment on the deleted answer is way more problematic than an obtuse edit to the question: "I appreciate your efforts on answering the question but as it doesn't try to clear things out it is not worth it and the user didn't politely reply to the comments. Moreover, I got his downvotes so...".  I'm not a php expert, so maybe the answer wasn't good, but to me it looks like you campaigned to have a relevant answer deleted because it might have helped a person who you were arguing with. I don't think anyone came out of this looking good.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The question wasn't clear and still is not. That's why OP said under the answer  *it never helped me at all* and cast a downvote on it.

Comment: Unkind flags can have repercussions for the user if multiple of their comments are flagged as unkind, so in cases where something is not clearly unkind, the flags often get declined yet the comments deleted. In this case, seeing the OP's lack of common filler words ("But not working" missing 'is' and "Actually he started downvote first" missing 'to') might lead a moderator to think this person's first language is not English, and thus their comment might not be an attempt to be unkind, but rather misunderstood humor or something else without unkind intent. Mods have to make many such choices.

Comment: Though of course I'm not a moderator so that's not an answer, the moderator who handled your flag would have to give the real train of thought.

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for all the downvotes here.

Comment: Voting on meta is weird.

Comment: @Revo re:downvotes; It could be because your question is formatted oddly. Instead of quoting the question, you posted a picture of it. Instead of quoting the comments, you put them in italics as part of your sentence. I had to read your question a couple of times to get what you were asking and what was being quoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but I felt the title was a bit baity, which didn't sit well with me and might have predisposed me to dismiss your post. In the end, I edited the title and upvoted your question, but I think that many times a slighly inflammatory (or inflamed) tone tends to work badly in meta. That being said, I really feel that discussing votes is quite unproductive.

Comment: @DavyM Because I didn't want to quote a question which I have linked to it. And for the picture I wanted to make the corresponding edit bold so that the difference could be seen. I shouldn't have quoted the comments too because I wasn't sure about all the words in them. Hence italicizing.

Comment: @yivi Thank you for both your comment and edit.

Comment: *Because I didn't want to quote a question which I have linked to it.* 1) Users under 10K can't access deleted posts. 2) "enter image description" is not useful for users who can't see the image either.

Comment: @BSMP Question got deleted one hour after I asked on meta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like it might have been due to the way the flags on this question were processed. Several of your comments had been flagged as harassment, and you had flagged the insulting comment in the middle of those. I'll ping the moderator responsible, but my guess is that they went to decline all the misplaced harassment flags and processed yours in the same batch.

All the comments involved were deleted, as they appeared to be obsolete after the edit to the question. Declined comment flags don't work against you, so I wouldn't be too worried about this one declined flag. The comment was deleted, so the end result was correct.

As for the serial downvotes you received, those should be invalidated by the system within a day or so. If they aren't handled after that time, flag us again and let us know to get them manually invalidated.